# Rounding to two decimal places issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, rounding

I am loading numeric values to 2 decimal places using Javascript. All values seem okay, apart from £299.90 and £499.90, which loads as £299.9 and £499.9

**Current code:**

```
//ROUNDING FUNCTION
function round(num, decimals) {
     return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);
}

//LOADING VALUES - Line cost variable is £49.99/£29.99 * 10
jQuery(".content").html("£" + round(lineCost, 2));
```

**What I have tried:**

```
jQuery(".content").html(parseFloat(lineCost * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

jQuery(".content").html(Number(lineCost).toFixed(2));
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `jQuery(".content").html(Number(lineCost).toFixed(2));` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `toFixed` method on a `float`/`integer` value:

```
var value = 0.127456;
    value.toFixed(2);
```

Output:

```
0.13
```

In your case:

```
jQuery(".content").html("£" + lineCost.toFixed(2));
```

If `lineCost` is a string, parse it to float:

```
jQuery(".content").html("£" + parseFloat(lineCost).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are over complicating it.

It just requires

```
parseFloat(lineCost).toFixed(2);
```

Here is [**a demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ssr57/).

Comment: your solution worked, thanks! someone just beat you to it though! sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Actually rounding means to convert a number like `10.5` to `11` or `12.49` to `12` so you should not round the number if you want to use a `float` with decimals, instead you should just use something like this:

```
var lineCost = 12.5;
parseFloat(lineCost).toFixed(2);
```